Select data after a set of data sequence
London
Chocolate 7  12/6/2023
Vanila    6  11/6/2023
Rose      5  10/6/2023
California
Chocolate 7  11/5/2024
Vanila    6  10/5/2024
Rose      5  09/5/2024
I would like to pull all data after the sequence table result = 7.  The startdate of an item after the sequence table 7.  AFter the date 12/6/2023
Any idea please.
Tried to subset table, did not work.
